# Absolute Paths with Gulp Mocha and Browserify

Tags: unit-testing, mocha.js, browserify, gulp-mocha

I have a project which is using [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) and ES6 to handle importing and defining packages.  The project is using absolute paths using the 'paths' option when building with [Gulp-Browserify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-browserify).

This works fine for the source code, but now I am attempting to write tests with [Mocha](https://mochajs.org/) and run them using [gulp-mocha](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-mocha) and this is causing problems.  Mocha is expecting relative paths, but if I give it a relative path to a file that has other imports using absolute paths, testing will fail with a MODULE_NOT_FOUND
error.

for example

```
Mocha Import at test/actions/user.js:
      import createUser from '../../src/actions/user';
      ...

Source Import at src/actions/user.js:
      import CREATE_USER from 'constants/use
      ...
```

will cause a MODULE_NOT_FOUND_ERROR

What I'm wondering is if there is any way to set an absolute path list in mocha similar to how you can for browserify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [app-require-path](https://www.npmjs.com/package/app-require-path). Just install it as a dev dep and add the following two files:

**test/mocha.opts**

```
--require test/_bootstrap.js
```

**test/_bootstrap.js**

```
require('app-require-path')(__dirname + '/..');
```

And that's it. You can change the path in *_bootstrap.js* to whatever you want. You can also add multiple paths. It's up to you.

Comment: Thanks! I found that [app-module-path](https://www.npmjs.com/package/app-module-path) worked cleaner with ES6, but this definitely put me in the right direction.